# I am not getting the SwipeRefreshLayout with the circled refresh instead i am getting Horizontal Refresh

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

The problem is I am not getting the SwipeRefreshLayout with the circled refresh instead I am seeing horizontal lines refresh on the top of the image. When I am running the same project in studio it is showing circled refresh but in eclipse it is showing changing horizontal lines when i pull down the list.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bgb2c12vgjo8cv0/Screenshot_2015-04-13-22-50-22.png?dl=0 -- this is what I don't want
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3uty87jz4f1sl38/Screenshot_2015-04-13-22-53-32.png?dl=0
-- I want to see the refresh like this

Comment: Are you using support.v4 library ?

Comment: Android Studio or Eclipse?

Comment: eclipse please... its an old project needed an update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use stock support v4 library (SwipeRefreshLayout is only available in support v4) then you need to update the version to current one.

Comment: how to implement SwipeRefreshLayout in v7 then??

Comment: If you use v7 appcompat then support v4 is already there. So if your SwipeRefreshLayout is a stock one then simply update your library.

Comment: Thanx for the help!!! I just imported the project into another workspace and the magic happened... eclipse is really confusing... Android studio is best please rate up the question so i can add images next time i ask questions